# Unable to fetch data from View's columns

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to reflect a view from a MySQL database with SQLAlchemy. Post reflection, I am trying to fetch data from the view but it doesn't work. 
I have the following code in my  initializedb.py:

```
dev=DBSession2.execute("select project from myView where code='1223'").first()

temp=str(dev.project)
```

WHen I initialize the db I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'project'
```

The following is the code for reflecting **myView** within my models.py:

```
Base2=declarative_base()
engine2= create_engine('mysql://<pathtomydb>')
meta=MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine2)
class myView(Base2):
    __table__=Table('myView',meta,Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),autoload=True,autoload_with=engine2)
    __tablename__='myView'
```

I have reflected two other tables and they work fine. Can somebody please tell me why this view doesnt get reflected?

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting all the libraries and reinstalling the daemons and requirements. It has to be a misconfiguration on your side.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think that this will fix her problem so it is possible answer.

Comment: Hi I dont think it is a misconfig since I am able to fetch columns from other reflected tables... Only this view cannot be accessed.